# How can my while loop wait until a method is finished before going onto another iteration in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am doing a tic tac toe game and I have basically finished everything just need to implement that you play on until someone wins 3 times. I have tried this loop but it goes infinitely after the first game. How can I make it to wait until the main() method has finished? Here is my code:-

EDIT: Here is the whole code. I dont understand because the first time it waits until the method is done but then it goes into infinity doesent even let me do anything

```
import random
#initializacija programa in delovanja
rezultat = [
    [" ", " ", " "," "],
    [" ", " ", " "," "],
    [" ", " ", " "," "],
    [" ", " ", " "," "]
]

zmage1 = 0
zmage2 = 0

igralec = 'O'

def main():
    izpis()
    while True:
        if isOver() == True:
            print(preveriZmagovalca())
            break
        if aliJeIzenačeno() == True:
            print('Igra je izenačena')
            break
        poteza(igralec)
        if isOver()==False:
            zamenjajIgralca()

def izpis():
    tabela = ['+-1-+-2-+-3-+-4-+', 
    'a %s | %s | %s | %s |' %(rezultat[0][0],rezultat[0][1],rezultat[0][2],rezultat[0][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'b %s | %s | %s | %s |' %(rezultat[1][0],rezultat[1][1],rezultat[1][2],rezultat[1][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'c %s | %s | %s | %s |' %(rezultat[2][0],rezultat[2][1],rezultat[2][2],rezultat[2][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'd %s | %s | %s | %s |' %(rezultat[3][0],rezultat[3][1],rezultat[3][2],rezultat[3][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+']
    [print(i) for i in tabela]

def isOver():
    global rezultat
    #horizontalno preverjanje konca igre
    for el in rezultat:
        if len(set(el))==1 and " " not in set(el):
            return True
    #vertikalno preverjanje igre
    for i in range(len(rezultat)):
        a = set()
        for el in rezultat:
            a.add(el[i])
        if len(a)==1 and " " not in a:
            return True
    #diagonalno preverjanje igre
    if len(set([r[i] for i, r in enumerate(rezultat)]))==1 and " " not in set([r[i] for i, r in enumerate(rezultat)]) or len(set([r[-i-1] for i, r in enumerate(rezultat)]))==1 and " " not in set([r[-i-1] for i, r in enumerate(rezultat)]):
        return True
    return False

def poteza(igralec):
    global rezultat
    vnos = 'g6'
    while vnos[0] not in ['a','b','c','d'] and vnos[1] not in [1,2,3,4]:
        vnos = input('Vnesite potezo %s: ' %igralec)
    vnos = [c for c in vnos]
    if vnos[0]=='a':
        vnos[0] = 0
    elif vnos[0]=='b':
        vnos[0] = 2
    elif vnos[0]=='c':
        vnos[0] = 2
    elif vnos[0]=='d':
        vnos[0] = 3
    if rezultat[int(vnos[0])][int(vnos[1])-1] == ' ':
        rezultat[int(vnos[0])][int(vnos[1])-1] = igralec
    izpis()


def zamenjajIgralca():
    global igralec
    if igralec == 'O':
        igralec = 'X'
    elif igralec == 'X':
        igralec = 'O'

def preveriZmagovalca():
    global igralec1
    global igralec2
    global zmage1
    global zmage2
    if igralec1[1] == igralec:
        return 'Zmagovalec je %s' %igralec1[0]
        zmage1 += 1
    else:
        return 'Zmagovalec je %s' %igralec2[0]
        zmage2 += 1
def aliJeIzenačeno():
    global rezultat
    for r in rezultat:
        if " " in set(r):
            return False
    return True


#main game
igralec1 = input('Vnesite ime igralca 1: ')
igralec2 = input('Vnesite ime igralca 2: ')
r = random.randint(1,10)
if r%2==0:
    igralec1 = igralec1.split()
    igralec1.append('O')
    igralec2 = igralec2.split()
    igralec2.append('X')
    print('%s ima prvo potezo' %igralec1[0])
    izpis()
elif r%2==1:
    igralec1 = igralec1.split()
    igralec1.append('X')
    igralec2 = igralec2.split()
    igralec2.append('O')
    print('%s ima prvo potezo' %igralec2[0])
while True:
    main()
    if zmage1==3:
        print('Tri zmage je dosegel %s' %igralec1[0])
        break
    elif zmage2==3:
        print('Tri zmage je dosegel %s' %igralec2[0])
        break
```

Comment: Where do you update `zmage1` and `zmage2`?

Comment: What happens in `main()`

Comment: Also, can you edit your title? It doesn't appear to reflect your actual problem. You *are* waiting for a method to finish before going on to another iteration - your actual problem is that this is an infinite loop.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica i update them in the method that tracks wins so where it prints out who won. And why does it go normaly the first iteration and then go crazy?

Comment: Side note: this isn't the cause of the problem, but there's no need to explicitly compare to `True` and `False` - in fact, it's considered poor style.

Comment: If it's going crazy after the first loop, it probably means you forgot to reset some variables.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why would `len(set(el))==1` be true?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to reset the board after every iteration that's why it went crazy because it thought it won everytime.